# Error on installation on iPhone, iPod devices "Application exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault"

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I tried to install my application on the devices by using Build and Run from xCode, the application works fine, but when I quit, in the springboard there's no icon for the application, I found the following log on the device's console (which I takes from the Organizer application)

```
Wed Oct 20 17:05:48 iPod-01 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.company.app[0x4cbb][1689]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.app[0x4cbb]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3252 (24226):3


Wed Oct 20 17:05:48 iPod-01 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.company.app[0x4cbb][1689]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.app[0x4cbb]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:2681 (24226):10


Wed Oct 20 17:05:48 iPod-01 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.company.app[0x4cbb][1689]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.app[0x4cbb]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed.


Wed Oct 20 17:05:48 iPod-01 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.company.app[0x4cbb][1689]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.app[0x4cbb]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault


Wed Oct 20 17:05:48 iPod-01 com.apple.debugserver-48[1688] <Warning>: 1 [0698/1403]: error: ::read ( 4, 0x3809f4, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)


Wed Oct 20 17:05:48 iPod-01 SpringBoard[27] <Warning>: Application 'AppPlus' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault
```

On the simulator, there's no error at all. Someone has any thought about the issue?